# How plausible is exoskeletal power armor for a tailed species?

Tags: technology

So, my firm was contracted to design a series of exoskeletal powered armor (EPA). You've surely familiar with the concept from the likes of [Iron Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Man) or [Master Chief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Chief_(Halo)) (probably many other examples). Well, there were a lot of challenges, but we pulled it off!

Er... mostly.

See, there's a wrinkle. (Ahem. Since you're from that other universe, you may not know that people in *our* universe are what you might call "anthropomorphic animals". Not just one species, either.) Thing is, while our ursine (that's what you'd call them, anyway) and homonine customers are quite happy... we ran into a snag trying to accommodate the canines and felines (and some others, but those two are rather more prominent). We managed to sort out the articulation on arms and legs (only a couple of joints, somewhat limited range of motion) and on the hands (small targets, we were able to skimp a little on the armor to keep everything fitting, and, well, still somewhat limited range of motion). Tails, however, are giving us a little trouble. They're about the same size as an arm, but much more flexible, requiring about a dozen omnidirectional joints. (Incidentally, [this question](/questions/87585) was helpful in suggesting what our armor might look like.)

Now, for our clients, tucking their tail against a leg or up against their chest is not an option (it's not just uncomfortable, it does bad things to their balance and screws with their muscle memory in a way that is decidedly counterproductive for what's supposed to be a combat system). Nor is simply not armoring the tail. First, because the armor also serves as a vacuum-rated environment suit, so leaving any part of the wearer exposed is simply not an option. Second, the suggestion that maybe the tail needed less protection... well, let's just say it wasn't received favorably.

...And my lead engineer just quit. (The jerk didn't even give notice! I think a rival corporation may have acquired him.) We're looking for someone else, but my boss is breathing down my neck to get an updated feasibility study finished ASAP.

So... I'm *really* hoping you all can help me out. Given that we got the other prototypes working, are tails going to be a cakewalk, or are there unforeseen issues that are likely to sink this part of the project? Are we going to be able to achieve the desired mobility and protection? (And are the users going to be able to *sit*?)

Oh, and the boss wants pictures; are there any technical issues I should keep in mind that will have a significant impact on the appearance of the final system?

Really appreciate your help!

p.s. In response to a comments: yes, it's *powered*. This is not only to reduce user fatigue, but to allow the system to enhance the user's natural strength.

---

(Out of universe) I don't want to [reality-check](/questions/tagged/reality-check) this because EPA is already somewhat unrealistic, but that's more or less what I'm looking for; if I can build EPA for a bear, can I build it for a tiger, given the tail? And what might it look like, given the unique design considerations (omnidirectional joints, in particular)?

Comment: Is the armor bulky enough that the powered exoskeleton is needed to even move inside the armor? Or is it purely an augmentation designed to boost strength which could comfortably worn unpowered? You could get away without augmenting the tail's strength and avoid all the complicated mechanics if it's the latter, but not if it's the former.

Comment: "What would it look like" is the part that seems entirely up to you as the writer. You want to have it change skins? It changes skins, no problem.

Comment: actually articulating the shoulder joint is still a big problem, while a tail is pretty simple, space suits already have lots of hoses.

Comment: @John, hoses aren't usually *armored*, are they? The majority of the suit is equivalent to plate armor (ahem: refer to examples); even the fingers have plate armor (possibly thinner than on the chest and limbs). The tail should be similarly armored.

Comment: @Rottweileronmarket-day., sorry, I maybe need to clarify... I'm not asking in terms of paint job, but e.g. would it be a bunch of tube-like shapes stacked inside of each other, or something else? The nature of the joints will influence the appearance, like how samurai armor, because of its design, has distinctive visual elements.

Comment: This depends a lot on what the tail is used for a prehensile tail is going to be very different than something like a wolf tail, We have never found a good way to armor the tactile portion of a grasping appendage.

Comment: @John, prehensile tails presumably have the same issues as fingers, which presumably (read: the question as worded assumed) are solved. Anyway, I'm mainly interested in e.g. wolf tails. (I would expect similar principles to apply to tails of felines, bovines... any "full-length", non-prehensile tail, anyway, excluding some odd ones such as e.g. beaver tails.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that the power armour is meant to augment how much the wearer can lift by doing most of the work for them. But does that function have to exist for each separate part? Presumably most of it is just protective plating. And so the tail can be left without complicated machinery.

Unless the tails are prehensile and regularly used for manipulation, you can just wrap them in scales or plates for protection. They would be flexible (because of the joints), shielded and possibly even light to allow for whatever balancing they need.

This is a model of a more traditional armour on a big cat that wraps the tail in smaller plates:

https://free3d.com/3d-model/tiger-in-armor-rigged-5227.html

Comment: Actually, the tail probably would need to be powered even if the rest *isn't*. (It is, but...) Tails (well, non-prehensile tails, which are what I'm dealing with) aren't built for tossing more than their own weight around, so sticking a bunch of heavy armor plating on them without some sort of power-assist mechanism is going to make them much less mobile. The link has something useful that I actually hadn't thought of already, however, which is to (plate-)armor only the *outside* of the tail; this would greatly simplify the joint design.

Comment: Have you considered a Bowden cable or hydraulics solution? Similar to brake cables transferring work from the pedal to the brake or how fingers are driven by muscles in the forearm. You can have cables or tubes run along the tail and any movement will create a feedback to tighten or release them through work done by servos and motors in the lower back region where the tech could fit.

Comment: Sure, something like that probably makes sense. I'm not really looking for implementation details, though, so much as how the armor articulation would work.

Answer (score 3):

**Sequential articulation.**

Articulation needs to occur in a tail both in the wiggle and the waggle directions.

The articulations that allow swimming could serve as template, [Robo Dolphin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgVzs1FWNM4) demonstrates how much control has been achieved so far for vertical strokes (waggle). The same principle applies for wiggle (horizontal strokes).

Since the combined articulation of wiggle and waggle is tough in a single artificial joint, I'd suggest sequential wiggle, waggle, wiggle, waggle joints and their associated [electroactive polymer contractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroactive_polymers) to occur in sequential joints, mediated by the usual strain sensors and cushioning that you might find on any other part of an articulated body.

<sup>Yes folks it's "how much is that doggy in the window the one with the **wiggly** tail" (horizontal movements).</sup>

Comment: Yeah, a series of joints whose range-of-motion alternates at 90° angles is exactly one of the options I was considering. Any thoughts what that would look like?

Comment: I'll see if I can dig out a schematic or still-frame of the structure. It'll be in a few hours, but I'll be on it later. @Matthew

Answer (score 3):

Tails evolved to assist with balance and therefore movement e.g a kangaroos should be much much easier to build armor for than as tail evolved for communication or load bearing e.g. that of say a cat or a new world monkey.

This is because in the case of the former the tail tends to be stiffer and less flexible so the powered joints/articulations & musculature etc can be fewer in number and less complex in design/construction.

In the case of the latter (depending on the species) the tail will be highly flexible more or less along its entire length so articulators, joints and 'ribbed' sections of armor etc will be required all the way along. This makes the design of this sort of 'tail armor' much more complex, expensive and demanding.

Comment: While useful information, I think you've managed to mainly restate *why* I'm asking the question. "[The] design of this sort of 'tail armor' [is] much more complex, expensive and demanding" is exactly the problem.

Comment: If its just dog and cat tails don't bother. These animals tails rest naturally in a 'upwards' position i.e curling up and over the back when at rest and then moving to express emotional states etc. In a bipedal character this means their tails will tend to tend to arch upwards behind the spine.  So just build a shaped  'tail space' onto the rear of the torso armor.  It would look a little weird - like the character was wearing a cross between a large armored fanny pack and a parachute but no joints or articulation would be required. The tail just wiggles freely under the torso armor.

Comment: "tails rest naturally in a 'upwards' position" ­— citation very much needed. A [simple image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wolf+walking&tbm=isch) contradicts your assertion; the "natural" position would appear to be somewhere between down and out (in line with the spine), which also makes far more sense logically. You may be confused by domestic animals which may frequently be expressing friendliness; an emotion an EPA wearer is probably not going to be expressing that often.

Comment: If you think I'm going to send you multiple links to photos of cats bums think again. Point is just have a large pack on the lower back with room inside for the tail to move freely in over most of its natural arc. Even if its normal rest state is 'down' (which was never specified BTW) it can rest comfortably on the base of the tail space. At the least its cheap, effective and can be produced immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Exoskeleton armor consists out of 4 things:

- the exoskeleton. A supportive structure that carries the weight of all components attached to it.
- the armor. This can be attached in any shape and size as long as the exoskeleton can support it.
- the actuators and motors that move the exoskeleton or keep it in place
- all additional components like powerplants, batteries, oxygen, environmental protection etc.

You already have a modifyable template for the exoskeleton useable for different species. That means you also have an exoskeleton version of the spinal column. Between the spinal column and a tail, the spinal column is harder to simulataneously articulate, actuate and armor.

You use a small version of the spinal column exoskeleton to create the tail segment with enough articulation. You only have to do this on one side and use ribs attached to these spinal segments to surround the tail as supports for the armor that overlays it. This armor would likely be a composite with air-tight layers on the inside for environmental protection and hardened plates on the outside.

Note that the tail section will likely be thicker on the side that actuates. You have to look at individual species to see how they use their tail to see where the articulation needs to happen. A creature that only uses it for balance would want the actuators and spinal segments to be on to top or bottom of the tail so the thicker actuators dont impede the maximum side-to-side motion of the tail and dont mess with the center of gravity. A species that grabs things with their tail would likely need the actuators on the side, likely using actuators and spinal segments on both sides simultaneously to improve coordination and keep the tail balanced, both in weight and in the strength with which it coils and grabs items.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking nature itself can be your guide.  In prosthetics, the holy grail is to be able to reproduce natural motion.  Advanced armor should have the same goal in mind.

Here is what I imagine.  First, a tail is a column of joints, none of which have a huge range of motion taken individually, but in combination can do quite a bit. You don't need a huge range of motion with each section.

So build your tail armor like an actual tail.  Same number of sections as there are bones in the tail.  Each section is a hollow tube.  Like the cartilage between the tail bones, each joint has a layer of a squishy material in a channel and the next section fits into the channel so that it can wobble freely over the full range of motion.  No need for a hinge as the flex comes from the compression of the squishy material.  stack up the sections for as long as you need.

Now for the power assist.  Just copy the natural body again.  Use the same connection points you find in the anatomy of the tail.  Your "muscle" can be a servo with cables or whatever highly advanced system you come up with.  Just keep the actuator and linkage proportionally close to the natural range of motion.  That should allow the tail to move pretty naturally.

I am assuming you have already accounted for taking feedback from the wearers own body as the input for the power armor.  You will need to account for extra processing power for the tail.

Edit:  If you want to visualize what I'm thinking with the joints, take a simple tumbler type drinking cup, like you might get from a fast food joint.  take a dish sponge and stuff it down into the cup.  Now take a second, identical cup and put it in the first so it is resting on the sponge.  You can move the two cups around 360 degrees without twisting and with an overlap so that in your armor, noting on the tail would be exposed.

Also, make sure the tail has adequate mass.  If a creature uses the tail to some degree for balance then it needs to have mass in proportion to the body, again, just like you might see in nature.

Comment: Hmm... I was actually forgetting about the mass, although "adeqaute" shouldn't be a problem; add some lead, or something (depleted uranium is probably contraindicated). Too *much* mass OTOH might be an issue... or not; keeping the tail lower would compensate, and maybe the users are able to do this instinctively.

Comment: @Matthew it would also help to pay attention to mass distribution as well.  Loading mass at the far end of the tail would be even worse for the uses than not adding any at all.

Comment: I wouldnt add as many sections to the tail as there are bones. When they articulate each section has their own movement circle, you want the movement circle of each section to coincide as much as possible with that of the relevant tail-bone(s). Having one less and placing them above the joint could give you a smoother motion with greater potential movement.

Comment: @Demigan perhaps.  I'm no engineer.  I just figure that the fewer joints, the more natural movement would be impeded.  The goal is to match the natural movement

Comment: @PaulTIKI I havent done the math, but a 1:1 ratio is definitely not the way to go. You need to shift the location of the joints so they dont overlap with the real one's or they'll stiffen if you try to bend them.

Answer (score 0):

**concentric rings.**

Use the solution many armored animals use, concentric rings of armor, non-prehensile tails are not that flexible so you don't actually need many joints, no worse than a limb.
[image]

As a bonus its is fairly easy to "power" real mechanical tentacles use either cable or artificial muscles set in opposing pairs. Cable allows for more fluid motion and a greater range of motion while artificial muscle between each segment gives your finer control but also a lot more complexity. You are simply expanding one of these to leave room on the inside. And you don't even need to do that too much, once you compress down the hair there really is not much mass or volume to a canid tail.

[image]

[image]